# Import data from remote database

Tags: migrations

I want to import locations from my remote **non drupal** database. I can't use **feed** as it does duplication. Is there any custom solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal!

If you don't want to use feed then I suggest query the data and insert it into your Drupal site using rest services. You can find dozen resources on how to use services. I would suggest to allow anonymous user to add location for testing purpose one example is like this

```
foreach ($locations as $key => $value) {


       $location_node = array(
        'type' => 'recording', //content type e.g. 'page' or 'article'
        'title' => 'test layer',
        'body[und][0]' => array('value' => 'This is my test value'),


);

}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks, I got a rough idea. I will post here if I stuck somewher

Answer (score 1):

Generally the migrate module is very flexible.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I worked it out with rest api and a custom php script